# Logging output from autostarted program (LXDE-pi/autostart)

Tags: boot, lxde, logfiles, systemd-startup

So I have a headless Pi CM4 running standard Raspbian, its only function is to [auto-start](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=294014) an application at boot which is invoked from `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

I would like to log the output of this application, however bash-style redirection appears not to work from within the `autostart` file.

So, what's the best solution to simply log the output of the app to a file from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a way to do it, and IMHO it's a useful snippet of Linux-fu too thanks to this SO question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834605/1389218

Specifically the details on snooping for a process's file descriptors which showed me that the process in fact IS writing to a log file already, so I could simply view it:

```
$ ps -ax | grep myapp
```

This shows my PID to be 581, so:

```
$ ls -l /proc/581/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 pi pi 64 Dec  8 15:29 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 pi pi 64 Dec  8 15:29 1 -> /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log
l-wx------ 1 pi pi 64 Dec  8 15:29 2 -> /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Dec  8 15:39 15 -> 'socket:[20569]'
lr-x------ 1 pi pi 64 Dec  8 15:29 3 -> 'pipe:[19884]'
l-wx------ 1 pi pi 64 Dec  8 15:29 4 -> 'pipe:[19884]'
```

Etc... this is showing every FD my process has open - spot the log file, FD 1 and 2 (stdout & stderr) are writing straight into it, great!

```
$ tail -f /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log
```

Gives me the sweet debug output I crave.